# enable/disabled host's file

Tags: switch, hosts-file

Does anybody knows if there is an utility that enable/disable the "hosts' file"

Comment: on which os? linux? windows? server? client? why?

Comment: Bad idea as many software depends on localhost which is defined in the hosts file.

Comment: Anyone with access to write to the hosts file will have access to undo this.

Answer (score 4):

In UNIX you can use nsswitch. Default:

```
hosts:          files dns
```

If delete files:

```
hosts:          dns
```

/etc/hosts will not work

Answer (score 1):

What OS? In windows you can rename the file using a basic batch command, or your scripting language of choice. I've also noticed that Windows will cache DNS resolution, so you'll also need to run "ipconfig /flushdns" afterwards.